# sql to get intersection in a many to many relation

Tags: sql, oracle, set, many-to-many, intersection

I have 2 tables `C` and `G`, and the many-to-many association table `CG` which contains 2 columns `c.id and g.id`. The query that I want to perform is:

`find the set of names in G that are common to a given set of names in C.`

Say, `c1` is linked to `g1` and `g2`, and `c2` is linked to `g2` and `g3`, and I ask for the common set for `{c1, c2}`, the answer is `{g2}`. The `{c1, c2}` will be provided with a WHERE...IN clause.

Any pointers to formulate this query, not using PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`.  Here is the general structure:

```
select g.id
from cg
where c.id in (. . .)
group by g.id
having count(distinct case when c.id in (. . .) then c.id end) = # items in list
```

Here is an example for four items:

```
select g.id
from cg
where c.id in (1, 3, 5, 7)
group by g.id
having count(distinct case when c.id in (1, 3, 5, 7) then c.id end) = 4
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's not giving me the right answer. Here is what I have: select id from C; shows 2 rows: 10 and 20   select id from G; shows  3 rows:1, 2 and 3   select * from CG; shows 4 rows (CID, GID): (10, 1), (10, 2), (20, 2), (20, 3). So the common set for both C's 10 and 20 should be just the gid 2. But when I try select g.id
from c, cg, g
where c.id in (10, 20)
group by g.id
having count(distinct case when c.id in (10, 20) then c.id end) = 2; I get  3 rows 1, 3 and 2. Basically all 3 gid's are being returned, instead of the intersection set which is {2} only.

Comment: The queries in your comment are nothing like my query.  Have you tried the query in the solution.  Hint:  there is only one table in the `from` clause.

Comment: seems like the case ... end part is redundant and can be replaced by having count(distinct cid) = 4, since the WHERE has already selected links with those cids only. i am not finding a counterexample where dropping the case would not work.

Comment: @labrat43 . . . The `case` is redundant in this case.  However, if you were looking for *only* the four ids and nothing else, then you would want it.  I guess I put it in as a matter of habit just to be careful.

Comment: Regarding the from part (`from cg`), shouldn't `c` and `g` also be included in the from part?